# How do I create a content class for template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create a template based on the theme settings which call on the `main-content` class.
My template.php file is:

```
`<?php /** * Template Name: Post Half Width Column
 * Template Post Type: post
*/ ?>
<?php
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-template', get_template_directory_uri() .        '/css/half-width.css' );
get_header();
?>
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content" class="post-main-content">
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile;
?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->
<?php
get_footer();
?>`
```

The original theme template specified `class="main-content"` instead of `class="post-main-content"`

I could not find where the `.main-content` was in .css checking the standard places so I thought I could just create my own .css in the child theme that includes:

```
`#post-main-content {
padding: 28px 28px 10px;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
}`
```

And then copy the rest from the themes style.css 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `#` is used to denote an `id` attribute, not a `class` attribute. To target a class in CSS use `.post-main-content`. Also, you don't need to copy all the CSS from the parent theme as it should automatically be inherited. That's assuming that the stylesheet was enqueued correctly. Refer to: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Okay so I understand how I was doing this wrong. I did not need to create a new class at all. so now my template referes to <div id="main-content" class="main-content"> and the .css just has .main-content {} the template shows up in my post screen in wordpress but nothing happens to the content. All i'm trying to do is make a single center column at 50% width

Comment: Looks like what?